# netmiko connect to device with different prompt

Tags: python, netmiko

I try to connect Cisco ACI using netmiko via console. The prompt on the login is not either > or # but "login as:".
[image]
I think because of that, I got the error.
If there anyway to sepcify the expected prompt or is there othe python module support it other than netmiko

Here is the code

```
device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_nxos",
    "ip": "****",
    "username": "****",
    "password": "****",
    "session_log": 'netmiko_session.log',
    "port": '22'
  }

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
```

Here is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\venv\aci_connect.py", line 13, in 
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 388, in ConnectHandler
return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 462, in **init**
self._open()
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 468, in _open
self._try_session_preparation()
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 963, in _try_session_preparation
self.session_preparation()
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco\cisco_nxos_ssh.py", line 14, in session_preparation
self._test_channel_read(pattern=r"[>#]")
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1202, in _test_channel_read
return self.read_until_pattern(pattern=pattern, read_timeout=20)
File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 721, in read_until_pattern
raise ReadTimeout(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:

Pattern not detected: '[>#]' in output.

Things you might try to fix this:

1. Adjust the regex pattern to better identify the terminating string. Note, in
   many situations the pattern is automatically based on the network device's prompt.
2. Increase the read_timeout to a larger value.